# How to create SqlParameter object with logical operators like and or contains in dotnet core to pass parameters to sql query

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have to create a dynamic query from C# and which will almost like below `SqlParameter`.

Here I have to include logical operators as well.

How can I include `contains`, `and`, `or` here?

Is it possible with `SqlParameter`? Or is there a better approach?

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
{    
     new SqlParameter("@first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).WithValue(to.FirstName),
     new SqlParameter("@last_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).WithValue = to.LastName)
     new SqlParameter("@middle_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).WithValue(to.MiddleName),
     new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).WithValue(to.EmpId)
};
```

Thanks
Krishnan

Comment: The **parameter** is just the value - it doesn't contain any logical operators or such. What your search code *does* with the parameter is entirely up to that code - the `SqlParameter` cannot and should not "tell* that code what to do .....

Comment: Do you use any ORM or are there only simple SQL Commands? Also is it possible for you to include an ORM (like dapper or ef).